# Regex doesn't fetch the nested curly braces

Tags: regex, perl

Curly braces matches sometimes and doesn't in few case.

My Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str1 = '$$\eqalign{&amp;\cases{\mathdot{\bf x}=A{\bf x}+Bu\cr y=H{\bf x}}\quad{\rm with}\{\bf x}=\left(\matrix{x\cr\mathdot{x}\cr\theta\cr\mathdot{\theta}}\right),\cr&amp;A\!=\!\!\left(\matrix{0&amp;1&amp;0&amp;0\cr 0&amp;0&amp;-{m_{a}\over M}g&amp;0\cr 0&amp;0&amp;0&amp;1\cr 0&amp;0&amp;{(M\!+\!m_{a})\over Ml}g&amp;0}\right)\!,\ B\!=\!\left(\matrix{0\cr{a\over M}\cr 0\cr-{a\over Ml}}\right)\!,\ H^{T}\!=\!\left(\matrix{1\cr 0\cr 1\cr 0}\right)\!.}$$';

my $str2 = "\\bibcite{Airdetal2013}{{2}{2017}{{{John} {et~al.}}}{{{James}, {Flexi}, {Buella}, {Curren}, {Mozes}, {Sam}, {Kandan}, {Alexander}, {Alfonsa}, {Fireknight}, {Georgen}, {Karims}, {Merloni}, {Nanda}, {Terra}, {Alvato}, {Nini}, {Winski}, {Shankar}, {Gnali}, \& {Giito}}}}";

my $regex = qr/(?:[^{}]*(?:{(?:[^{}]*(?:{(?:[^{}]*(?:{[^{}]*})*[^{}]*)})*[^{}]*)*})*[^{}]*)*/;

if($str1=~m/\{$regex\}/) {  print "str1: $&\n";  }
if($str2=~m/\{$regex\}/) {  print "str2: $&\n";  }


OUTPUT:

str1: {&amp;\cases{\mathdot{\bf x}=A{\bf x}+Bu\cr y=H{\bf x}}\quad{\rm with}\ {\bf x}=\left(\matrix{x\cr\mathdot{x}\cr\theta\cr\mathdot{\theta}}\right),\cr&amp;A\!=\!\!\left(\matrix{0&amp;1&amp;0&amp;0\cr 0&amp;0&amp;-{m_{a}\over M}g&amp;0\cr 0&amp;0&amp;0&amp;1\cr 0&amp;0&amp;{(M\!+ !m_{a})\over Ml}g&amp;0}\right)\!,\ B\!=\!\left(\matrix{0\cr{a\over M}\cr 0\cr-{a\over Ml}}\right)\!,\ H^{T}\!=\!\left(\matrix{1\cr 0\cr 1\cr 0}\right)\!.}

str2: {2}

str1 is correct output. str2 incorrect output.

Expected Output on str2 is:

 str2: {{2}{2017}{{{John} {et~al.}}}{{{James}, {Flexi}, {Buella}, {Curren}, {Mozes}, {Sam}, {Kandan}, {Alexander}, {Alfonsa}, {Fireknight}, {Georgen}, {Karims}, {Merloni}, {Nanda}, {Terra}, {Alvato}, {Nini}, {Winski}, {Shankar}, {Gnali}, \& {Giito}}}}
```

> In the sample str1 string doesn't matched with the nested curly braces. However the second sample str12 string can matched the nested curly braces.

This is my question can matched the nested curly braces. I am clueless. It would be better if someone point out my mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would be the correct output of Matched1?, Please add information explaining your regex string output!

Comment: It would be more clear if you explained what you want to match. Balanced `{...}` substrings after 0+ chars other than `{` and `}`? Use recursion/subroutines then: `/[^{}]*({(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})/`

Comment: I get `Match2: {2}` not `Match1: {2}` for the output. Why is `Match2: {2}` incorrect? Please explain

Comment: I have updated my question with brief details.

Comment: Your mistake is the wrong pattern that causes too heavy backtracking. Please define the requirements. If you need to match nested `{}`, you just need a recursive regex - `/{(?:[^{}]++|(?R))*}/`

Comment: `if($str2=~m/^\{(?:[^\{\}]++|(?R))*\}$/g) {  print "Match2: $&\n";  }` No its not matched the string.

Comment: Why did you add `^` and `$`? Remove them. No need to escape `{` and `}` here. See https://ideone.com/hqBS8w.

Comment: Or do you mean you need to validate a string with a balanced amount of nested braces?

Comment: No I need to grep the FIRST IN '{' LAST OUT '}' that means matched curly braces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137532/discussion-between-ssr1012-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your actual requirements ([discussed in the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137532/discussion-between-ssr1012-and-wiktor-stribizew)) are to match substrings starting with `\bib` followed with `{...}` substrings or any chars other than `{` and `}`, you should use a regex with a *subroutine*:

```
/\\bib(?:({(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})|(?!\\bib)[^{}])*/g
```

**Details**:

- `\\bib` - `\bib` literal text
- `(?:({(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})|(?!\\bib)[^{}])*` - 0+ occurrences of:

  - `({(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})` - Group 1 (that will be recursed with `(?1)`) matching

    - `{` - a literal `{`
    - `(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*` - 0 or more occurrences of 1+ chars other than `{` and `}` or the whole Group 1 subpattern
    - `}`   - a literal `}`
  - `|` - or
  - `(?!\\bib)[^{}]` - a char other than `{` and `}` not starting a `\bib` literal char sequence.

See the [sample Perl code](https://ideone.com/W3dLa8):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $str2 = "\\bibcite{Airdetal2013}{{2}{2017}{{{John} {et~al.}}}{{{James}, {Flexi}, {Buella}, {Curren}, {Mozes}, {Sam}, {Kandan}, {Alexander}, {Alfonsa}, {Fireknight}, {Georgen}, {Karims}, {Merloni}, {Nanda}, {Terra}, {Alvato}, {Nini}, {Winski}, {Shankar}, {Gnali}, \& {Giito}}}}";

while($str2 =~ /\\bib(?:({(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})|(?!\\bib)[^{}])*/g) {
   say "$&";
}
```

Comment: Note I added the `(?!\\bib)` lookahead with the last `[^{}]` so as not to eat up consequent matches (if you have multiple). You may further adjust that part, or even just use `[^{}\\]` to avoid matching ``\`` with that regex part.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**   The edit in the question adds `\\bibcite{Airdetal2013}` in front. However, this doesn't change the analysis below as it doesn't change the overall nesting levels.

---

This has got to be possible to do in a better way. There is recursive regex offered by [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) in comments. There are modules for recursive parsing. And there are tools for parsing Latex.

However, out of curiosity ...

Your string, shortened suitably

```
my $str2 = "{{2}{2017}{{{John}{et~al.}}}{{{James}, ... {Gnali}, \& {Giito}}}}";
```

or, with `C` standing for a pair of curlies with something inside (no nesting)

```
"{ C C { { C C } { C, ... \& C } } }"
```

So you have three levels of nesting, to get down to the last pair `{...}` (no further nesting).

Your regex, spread out and with `$nc = qr/[^{}]*/` (Non-Curlies), so that we can look at it

```
my $regex = qr/
    (?: $nc 
        (?: { 
            (?: $nc 
                (?: { 
                    (?: $nc (?: { $nc } )* $nc ) 
                    } 
                )* $nc 
            )* 
            } 
        )* $nc 
    )*/x;
```

I can count two levels here. (The `$nc` has no curlies so `{ $nc }` matches my `C` above.)

Thus this regex cannot match that whole string.

How to fix it? Best, find another way so to not drown in this.

Or, write it out like above, *very carefully*, and add the missing level.

Comment: @ssr1012  Oh goodness ... you need to be _really_ careful with something like that.  It can blow away answers, invalidate whole approaches. Thanks for letting me know :)  However, the edit doesn't change the analysis above -- it only adds one `C` in front (as I used `C` in the answer). Same overall level of nesting.

Comment: Its not matched my regex `my $str2 = "\\bibcite{Airdetal2013}{{2}{2017}{{{John} {et~al.}}}{{{James}, {Flexi}, {Buella}, {Curren}, {Mozes}, {Sam}, {Kandan}, {Alexander}, {Alfonsa}, {Fireknight}, {Georgen}, {Karims}, {Merloni}, {Nanda}, {Terra}, {Alvato}, {Nini}, {Winski}, {Shankar}, {Gnali}, \& {Giito}}}}";`

Comment: @ssr1012  What do you mean by that?  I shortened that in the answer on purpose, so that we can see that there are _three levels of nesting_ in the string.  But the regex only provides for two.  Thus the regex cannot match that whole string.

Comment: Ok I got and understand now.